# small navigation title is showing for few seconds

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have set large title in `viewWillAppear()`

```
 self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
 self.navigationItem.title = "Reports"
```

But still when I redirect to next VC and come back I can see navigation Title in small size for a while and then I see large title, anybody know why and how to fix it?

Comment: On next VC, I don't want largeTitleDisplayMode. On next VC I set

Answer (score 0):

If you want the next VC to have `largeTitleDisplayMode` **false**, you could try to set it in `viewWillDisappear()` of the current VC, like this:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set this in the `viewDidLoad` of your view controller, not the `viewWillAppear`. It's the first part in the [view lifecycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html) and where this work should be done